# How to install VLC on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: camera, vlc

Every time I try to install VLC on my Raspberry Pi I get this error

```
$sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a couple reasons why this is happening. First of all, update your repositories with the command `sudo apt-get update`. Then run `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

Comment: `apropos` searches the man page database; are you sure you don't mean `apt-cache search vlc`?

Comment: @DaveJones you are correct. I edited my answer.